# java- soap webservice using ksoap

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I want read data from a soap webservice. this is my code :

```
 final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webservicex.com/";
        final String URL = "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?op=GetCitiesByCountry";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "GetCitiesByCountry";
        TextView lblResult;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("CountryName","Germany");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            //SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            // SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;


            Log.v("this",resultsRequestSOAP.toString()+ " response");
            Log.v("this","Response::"+resultsRequestSOAP.toString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            SoapFault error = (SoapFault)envelope.bodyIn;
            Log.v("this","Error message : "+error.toString());
            Log.v("this","Error"+e);
        }
```

I think I've badly set data to variables. I get this error:

`Error message : SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?op=GetCitiesByCountry.
                                                                       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
                                                                       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
                                                                       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
                                                                      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@52739eac`

could you help me ? what is wrong with my code ?